# Get element from selected listview row

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView in Xamarin.Forms that uses data binding. I am using an ItemSelected event which gets the current index. I would like to get the price attribute of the selected ListView row. Using Tracepoint, I see the value in e => SelectedItem => Price.

[image]

How can I save this into a variable? I have tried:

```
double val = e.SelectedItem.Price;
```

However, this does not work.

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Price' and no accessible extension method 'Price' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found.

I would like to store the price of the selected ListView row into a variable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you had used data binding , you should handle all the logic in your ViewModel .

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding xxx}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectItem,Mode=TwoWay}" >
...
```

#### in ViewModel

```
public class YourViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

   

    private YourModel selectItem;
    public YourModel SelectItem
    {
        get
        {
            return selectItem;
        }

        set
        {
            if (selectItem!= value)
            {
                selectItem= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();

               double val = selectItem.Price;
               // do some thing you want here
            }
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

In your case , `Price` is the property of the model ,not the property of SelectedItem .Or you can improve your code like following. But as I said ,use MVVM is better .

```
var SelectItem = e.SelectedItem as YourModel;
double val = SelectItem .Price;
```